# Issue when deploying on GitHub pages

Tags: github-pages, docusaurus

I tried to host a project docs made with docoraus on GitHub with the name user.github.io. and in my vs it said

```
Successful hosted on https://user.github.io
```

And I own a domain with the same name as my GitHub user name say
.

```
https://user.me
```

Now when ever I am trying to open .my project

```
https://user.github.io
```

It's getting redirected to

```
https://user.me
```

GitHub project it's redirecting me to the other domain .

Comment: Can you share a link to your GitHub repository ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.